# RPC Wallet integration API throwing an error

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosio-code, rpc, c++

I am new with blockchain services. I have created wallet using command line.

```
curl -X POST   http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/wallet/create -d '"WalletTest"
```

It's created successfully.

But, I'm trying to create wallet using EOSIO RPC APIs in C++. I have used curl library for http call. But, Whenever I call, I am getting following error

```
2019-07-02T09:50:16.709 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:474           handle_exception     ] Exception Details: 4 parse_error_exception: Parse Error
```

Unexpected char '100' in "data"
    {"c":100,"s":"data"}
    thread-0  json.cpp:437 variant_from_stream

```
{"str":"data=mywallet"}
thread-0  json.cpp:460 from_string
```

My C++ Code:

```
CURL *hnd1 = curl_easy_init();

curl_easy_setopt(hnd1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_easy_setopt(hnd1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/wallet/create");
curl_easy_setopt(hnd1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=MyWallet");

struct curl_slist *headers1 = NULL;

curl_easy_setopt(hnd1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers1);
curl_easy_setopt(hnd1, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writefunc);
curl_easy_setopt(hnd1, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);
curl_easy_perform(hnd1);
printf("%s\n", s.ptr);
if(s.ptr != NULL)
free(s.ptr);
```

What am I miss here? Please someone help. Thank you.

Comment: even curl -X POST   http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/wallet/create -d '"WalletTest" is also  not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved that issue. We just need to pass wallet name as string.

```
curl_easy_setopt(hnd1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "MyWallet");
```

It's works for me. May be help someone.